# Why 1387568966 is an invalid Date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

This is my code:

```
var data = "1387568966 ";
var parsedDate = new Date(Date.parse(data));
```

but if I print parsedDate it says "Invalid Date".

Where am I wrong? It should works with timestamp.

Comment: [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a date with a timestamp use [the `Date` constructor taking a number as argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) (the number of milliseconds since Epoch) :

```
var data = "1387568966 ";
var parsedDate = new Date(data*1000); // converts from "seconds" to milliseconds
```

or

```
var parsedDate = new Date(parseFloat(data)*1000);
```

if you want to make your code more obvious.

Comment: great. but what does that plus sign do?

Comment: @gefei It forces the conversion of `data` to a number. You may use `parseInt` if the potential readers of your code aren't used to it.

Comment: It retuns `Sat Jan 17 1970 02:26:08 GMT+0100`, which is wrong. It's 20 December 2013....

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Data.parse()` wrong, it does the opposite of what you think.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> The Date.parse() method parses a string representation of a date, and
>   returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00
>   UTC.

*Instead, just parse your string into an integer and pass it to the date constructor.*